# How to print more than 3 values inside a tensor by using tf.Print()?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a following simple code for the purpose of splitting a tensor into three parts along `axis=1`

```
sess = tf.Session()
a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])

x, y, z = tf.split(a, 3, axis=1)

print_out_x = tf.Print(x, [x], message='Value of x: ', name='x_value')
print_out_y = tf.Print(y, [y], message='Value of y: ', name='y_value')
print_out_z = tf.Print(z, [z], message='Value of z: ', name='z_value')

sess.run([print_out_x, print_out_y, print_out_z])

print(print_out_x)
print(print_out_y)
print(print_out_z)
```

I got the output like below

[image]

How can I get full of values inside x, y, z instead of `...` by using `tf.Print()`? More sepcifically, I want output should be

```
Value of z: [[3][6][9][12]]
Value of y: [[2][5][8][11]]
Value of x: [[1][4][7][10]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Args](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print): `summarize` in the `tf.Print()` function to set the number of arguments that need to be printed per intput tensor.

For ex,

```
tf.Print(x, [x],summarize=x.shape[0], message='Value of x: ', name='x_value')
#Value of x: [[1][4][7][10]]
```